# Where can I find complex recipes?

Tags: resources

Very often when looking for recipes for something I want to try, I will only find "easy, ready in 20 minutes, one pot, etc." recipes. The problem is that I want to be challenged, I actively seek recipes that are NOT simple.

Where can I find recipes that dont cut corners to be simple?
Are there specific cookbooks known for this? Or websites?

Comment: There are *tons* of cookbooks (and websites) which don't cut corners, and unfortunately big lists are really awkward on Stack Exchange. It's not that we don't want to help, I know it can be difficult to search and discover how complex a given resource is without actually reading, it just doesn't work out too well here.

Comment: This is, I think, a legit question about culinary language/diction.

Comment: @Jefromi Yeah... That's kinda what I figured when I asked.

Comment: Adding "from scratch" when I search for a recipe online usually bumps up the complexity level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly want complex, I’d suggest the Alinea cookbook by Grant Achatz. This book highlights molecular gastronomy techniques  and recipes featured at his award winning restaurant in Chicago.

Another route to go would be to look for traditional recipes from different cooking heritages.  The James Beard Foundation will annually award the best cookbooks from around the world. These will be high-quality, no shortcuts, or traditional cooking.